# El uso de "partis pris"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

Estoy escribiendo un ensayo que habla de un grupo étnico y la discriminación y persecución que sufren.

¿Es apropriado usar la frase francesa "partis pris" para describir esto?

Comment: Así como lo presentas yo no lo entiendo. Si la audiencia del ensayo lo va a entender estaría bien, de lo contrario, no.

Comment: Yo tampoco me he enterado. No conozco la expresión francesa y tampoco me ha quedado claro qué quieres describir con ella. ¿Podrías ampliar un poco la pregunta?

Comment: En el español hay muchas expresiones en otros idiomas, empezando por el latín (in albis, tabla rasa, viceversa, ad infinitum, ...) y en otros idomas por supuesto. Algunas son más comunes y otras menos. No estoy 100% seguro, pero creo que esta expresión no la hemos "adoptado" en español. Si la hemos incorporado, creo que la iba a entender muy poquita gente. Si no explicas el término, me temo que la mayoría de tu audiencia no lo va a entender.

Comment: Perhaps if you expand on what the final esto in your question refers bcak to people here can suggest another phrase?

Comment: Aparentemente estás utilizando la versión inglesa [_parti pris_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parti_pris) de la expresión francesa _prendre parti_. ¿No sería mejor buscar algo que venga directamente del francés o, más rápido aún, un término español? Dale a [edit] para indicar qué quieres decir con este concepto, para que así podamos ayudarte. Yo nunca he oído la expresión en castellano, por cierto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Partis pris" es una voz francesa que significa "sesgo" o "prejuicio". La traducción por supuesto se puede ampliar según el contexto a "tomar partido por algo o alguien" o "predisposición por algo".

He aquí [algunos ejemplos, cortesía de Linguee](http://www.linguee.es/frances-espanol/traduccion/parti+pris.html).

Esta voz ni es de uso fecuente en español ni es un término que se haya incorporado al español.

Con esto quiero decir que nuestro idioma ha incorporado términos de otros idomas (hardware, software) que por supuesto se puede usar y prácticamente todo el mundo va a entender. Luego hay otros no oficialmente incorporados, pero que la gente entenderá en mayor o menor medida por cultura general (*please*, *thank you*, *ciao*, *auf wiedersehen*, *n'est ce pas*, *c'est la vie*...).

`Partis pris` no parce estar en ninguno de estos dos grupos, por lo que deberías explicar la expresión si vas a utilizarla, ya que no es realista suponer que toda tu audiencia lo va a entender sin problemas.